# How can I change the appearance of a <select> element in the Chrome browser?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.form input.disabled,
.form select.disabled,
.form textarea.disabled {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  border: 1px solid #adcede;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.form select.disabled option {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But it seems not to work with my HTML:

```
<form>
<select data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject" 
data-ng-model="option.selectedContentType" 
data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.contentTypes" 
class="ng-pristine ng-valid" 
disabled="disabled">
<option style="display: none" value="" class="">Select Content Type</option></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your CSS right now.

1. just use `form` not `.form` to refer to the element
2. You don't want `select.disabled` as that refers to a class, you want `select[disabled="disabled"]` as `disabled` isn't a class it's an attribute so you want to use the brackets as an attribute selector. You've also disabled the dropdown menu so I don't even know what the point of the last CSS statement is for, you seem to be trying to make the option transparent, which you can't because the dropdown is disabled.

Since you apparently want to make the form fully opaque despite being disabled, remove the option from your last CSS selector and make the above changes, and everything should work.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select data-ng-disabled="!option.selectedSubject" data-ng-model="option.selectedContentType" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in option.contentTypes" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" disabled="disabled">
        <option style="display: none" value="" class="">Select Content Type</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form input.disabled, form select.disabled, form textarea.disabled {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    border: 1px solid #adcede;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
form select[disabled="disabled"]{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HcaF2/

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS `.form select.disabled` is wrong based on your HTML.

It is looking for the following:
*any element with class 'form', select with class 'disabled'.*

The correct css would be:

```
form select:disabled {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  border: 1px solid #adcede;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Disabled is an attribute. You can get it with by using pseudo-selector `:disabled` (or even with `select[disabled=disabled]` which is attribute selector, but use the pseudo-class instead).

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/zJ7e7/)

P.s: There's no need to style `option` because since `select` is disabled, you can't click to open it. Just style select accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

use this plugin http://uniformjs.com/ it is easy to edit rly cool

Comment: He's not trying to style his dropdown menus, please read his question closely